# Intertext causes overfull hbox in align* environment

Tags: math-mode, spacing, mathtools

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
        \begin{align*}
        a & =b & & \text{if }         
                        \begin{dcases*}
                        x = 2 \\
                        \shortintertext{and}
                        y = 3
                        \end{dcases*}\\
        a & = c & & \text{ elswhere}
        \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

produces, as expected,

[image]

but it causes an

> Overfull \hbox (53.86888pt too wide) in paragraph

The `shortintertext` command seems to be the guilty one, is this use of it improper?

Comment: Why `\intertext{and}` and not simply ``\text{and}\\``?

Comment: To use `\shortintertext{and}` without having to tweak manualy the inter-space... (so, the example is not relevant, I'll edit it).

Comment: Both `\intertext` and `\shortintertext` should be used to interrupt a full display alignment, not a boxed one such as `aligned`, `gathered`, `cases` and similar ones.

Comment: If I use `\shortintertext{and}`, I get exactly the same spacing as with ``\text{and}\\`` (but with the overfull box warning).

Comment: Great, thank you. I'll accept any answer you give, or if you don't bother writing an answer, I'll try to write mine, quoting the references manuals, or just close my question.

Comment: @egreg -- with `\text{and}`, i get very much wider spacing between the left-hand "column" and the right-hand one.  that's avoided by using `alignat*` and inserting `\quad` as a left-hand-side spacer in one of the lines.  but the whole construct is centered, not shifted left (caused by the full-line width of the `\intertext` element).

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, of course: that's the normal horizontal spacing produced by `align`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands `\intertext` and `\shortintertext` should only be used to interrupt a full display environment (`align`, `alignat`, `flalign`) for keeping the alignment across two separated sets of formulas.

Both commands typeset a box as wide as the value of `\linewidth` outside the alignment. So it's not surprising you get an `Overfull \hbox` warning.

You just need `\text`; the spacing will be exactly the same as the one you get by abusing `\shortintertext`, but of course without the warning.

In the following, both inputs are compared.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a & =b & &
  \text{if }         
  \begin{dcases*}
  x = 2 \\
  \text{and}\\
  y = 3
  \end{dcases*}\\
a & = c & & \text{elsewhere}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
a & =b & &
  \text{if }         
  \begin{dcases*}
  x = 2 \\
  \shortintertext{and}
  y = 3
  \end{dcases*}\\
a & = c & & \text{elsewhere}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the `\shortintertext` version is pushed all the way left, because of the implied wide box.

If you want to reduce the gap between the two columns, use `alignat*`, for instance

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
a & =b &\quad &
  \text{if }         
  \begin{dcases*}
  x = 2 \\
  \text{and}\\
  y = 3
  \end{dcases*}\\
a & = c & & \text{elsewhere}
\end{alignat*}
```

[image]

Comment: arrggghhhh.  you beat me to this.  i still think that `alignat*` with a strategically placed `\quad` will look better.  also, get rid of the input space at the beginning of `{ elsewhere}`; that misalignment bugs me!

Comment: @barbarabeeton Done (I had already added the `alignat*` version).